# The tradeoff between a small and big performance window

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, churn

I'm developing a churn model and I don't know which size of performance window to choose.

My intuition is that if its size is too large (for example two years) the model will not succeed to predict it. Even if a model like that works, I'm not sure that it is useful. The same for a too-small performance window.

What is a reasonable performance window size range, and how can I choose it?

[image: performance window]

figure retrieved from [Altexsoft](https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/business/customer-churn-prediction-for-subscription-businesses-using-machine-learning-main-approaches-and-models/)

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "performance window" and what does the figure show? I don't think I heard this term ever before, so I guess this may apply to other users as well.

Comment: . Predictive modeling is about learning the relationship between observations made during a period (window) that ends before a specific time point and predictions about a period that starts after the same time point. The former period is referred to as observation, independent, explanatory window, or customer event history (let’s use the last definition for clarity). The latter period that follows an observation one is called a performance, dependent, or response window. In other words, we predict events (a user churns or stays) in a performance window, in the future.

Answer (score 1):

*It depends* on what is your data and what is the model that you are using for the data. There is no objective "too large" window where you cold predict ahead.

The window would depend on what is your data. If your data is aggregated every hour, it would be different than if it is aggregated every day, week, month, or year. The obvious constraint is that you need data from a longer period in the past, then the period you are going to predict. If you want to predict one week ahead, you need at least few weeks of data; for month ahead, you need few months; for year ahead, few years, etc. Some phenomenons have seasonal variability, in such a case you need few seasons of the data. So if you want to predict shopping behavior of your customers one week ahead, it would be wiser to have more than a year of the data so that you can account for the seasonality.

Another problem is data drift, your data changes over time and the old data may not be relevant anymore. In such a case, you may need to ignore some of the historical data, but foreseeing the drift, you probably do not want to make predictions too far ahead as well.

Finally, simpler models would need less data, more complicated ones would need more data. Another factor is how flexible is your model. For example, results of linear regression in most cases won't be very surprising, but polynomial regression, or neural network when used for extrapolation may give completely crazy results.